# IntelliJ IDEAにおいてRuby2.0の記法を使うとエディタ上にエラー表示される

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rbenv

IntelliJ IDEAを使用しRubyプログラムを行っています。
Ruby2.0からサポートされた記法がエディタ上でエラー表示されてしまい、これを解消できず困っています。
rbenvを用いてruby2.1.5をインストールし、rbenvのインストールディレクトリをプロジェクトのsdkに指定
しています。

---

#### エラー箇所

キーワード引数の記述箇所
[image: エラー]

#### エラー内容

`Named arguments are only supported by Ruby2.0 and RubyMotion projects`

#### プロジェクト設定内容

- Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project SDK -> `rbenv: 2.1.5`
- Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> `rbenv: 2.1.5`

  - Ruby interpreter path -> `/home/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby`
  - Language level -> `2.1`
  - Gems bin directory -> `/home/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin`

#### 開発環境

OS: Linux Mint17 (Windows7をホストとしVirtualBoxで起動）
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 14

---

エラーとなる原因として何が考えられるでしょうか。

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA のバージョンなど環境を追記されたほうが良いと思います。OSはOSXでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。情報を追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません。自己解決しました。

IntelliJ IDEAで初めにプロジェクトを作成する際に、
WEB MODULEを選択していたのが原因だったようです。

*.imlファイルのmodule要素を以下のように変更したところエラー表示がなくなりました。

修正前：`module type=WEB_MODULE"`
修正後： `module type=RUBY_MODULE"`

お騒がせしました。ありがとうございました。